# Update jsonb value in PostgreSQL using JOOQ

Tags: java, postgresql, sql-update, jooq, jsonb

In my Java project I'm usinq JOOQ and I want update JSONB value.
But my build failure.

I wrote a code:

```java
DSL.using(connection).update(USER_SETTINGS)
                .set(USER_SETTINGS.SETTING_VALUE, field("{\"filtersValue\":{\"page\":0,\"size\":100}, \"visibleCount\":100}", JSONB.class))
                .where(USER_SETTINGS.USER_ID.eq(98383L))
                .execute();
```

[image]

and I got a next message:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: 
SQL [update "sbcm_sys"."user_settings" set "setting_value" = "filtersValue":{"page":0,"size":100, "visibleCount":100} where "sbcm_sys"."user_settings"."user_id" = ?]; ERROR: syntax err
or at or near ":"
  Position: 71
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
  Position: 71
```

Where I made a mistake?

Comment: I changed field() to val() and it's work!

Answer (score 2):

You're using [`DSL.field(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field(java.lang.String)), which is used for [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), when you meant to use [`DSL.val(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#val(java.lang.String)), which is used for [bind values](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/).

See also this blog post for further clarifications: https://blog.jooq.org/whats-a-string-in-the-jooq-api/